# How can add a UI element above the first cell in the tableView in the IB?

Tags: ios

I have  a TableViewController with a UI element (cogwheel button) placed above the first cell.  I am able to do this by adding the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I then create the button programmatically

```
// Setting up menubutton
let menuButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, -45, 25, 25)
menuButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"menu55_White.png"),forState: UIControlState.Normal)
menuButton.addTarget(self, action: "didTapMenuButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(menuButton)
```

The setup makes the menuButton scroll away when the user scrolls down the tableview.

I did it programmatically because I was unable achieve the same result in the interface builder.  However it is now causing me issues with Autolayout.

**Question:** Is it a way to replicate this effect in the IB?
In other words, how can I place a UIImage above the first cell(only) in the tableView in the IB, so that I can create constraints for Autolayout. And if I can't, how can I replicate the effects of Autolayout programatically?

Any help would be very much appreciated - Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Drag a view from your object library and place it on the top of your table view controller and it will be set as its header view.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not possible to change the X, Y location of the object

Comment: You have to place a view first then your control.

Comment: I have added a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In IB you can create two prototype cells, one for the first cell with cogwheel button and another for the rest of the cell.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` put a condition on `indexPath.row` to know which cell to return.

Problem is that i am not familiar with swift.
You will have to create 2 prototype cells with different identifiers.
In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
if(indexPath.row == 0)
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"firstCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
else
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"otherCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Ok, that could work, if you could please explain a little more than that would be great, for example, do I use different identifiers? and how would I count rows, just add 1?